# Generating oracle error 00905

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle I'm attempting to create a function that combines first and last name.
every time I run the code below I get an **error 00905**.  a little red squiggly underline appears just under the @ sign next to @FirstName.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LastNameFirst 
          ( 
            @FirstName   CHAR(25),  
            @LastName    CHAR(25)
          )

RETURNS VARCHAR(60)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(60);

SET @FullName = RTRIM(@LastName) + ', ' + RTRIM(@FirstName);

RETURN @FullName;

END;
```

Comment: Your syntax has nothing to do with Oracle.  It is SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Oracle syntax would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LastNameFirst (
    in_FirstName IN VARCHAR2,
    in_LastName IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
    RETURN TRIM(in_LastName) || ', ' || TRIM(in_FirstName);
END;
```

Notable differences from SQL Server:

- The parameters can be specified as `in` and `out`, rather than as nothing (SQL Server doesn't allow output parameters on functions).
- Oracle does not require lengths for character parameters.
- The normal type for a string is `varchar2`.
- The concatenation character is `||` instead of `+`.
- `@` is not allowed in variable names.

Comment: You don't have to specify `IN` explicitly. If you leave it out, `IN` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

you could just revise your function to this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LastNameFirst ( FirstName IN VARCHAR2,LastName IN VARCHAR2)

    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
     FullName VARCHAR2(60);

    begin

    FullName := RTRIM(LastName) || ', ' || RTRIM(FirstName);

    RETURN FullName;
    end;
```

The assignment operator in PLSQL is `:=` not `=` and the concatenation operator is `||` not `+`